# How to detect if the phone is connected to power in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement to show a popup if the the phone is not currently charging/connected to power.  How do I achieve this in flutter?

Comment: Bases on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@abhishek.tech/how-to-create-custom-platform-specific-code-with-platform-channels-flutter-b8169cde5c7b) I believe you are able to add some logic to show a pop-up if the smartphone is not charging :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [battery package](https://pub.dev/packages/battery)

How it looks like:

```
// Import package
import 'package:battery/battery.dart';

// Instantiate it
var battery = Battery();

// Access current battery level
print(await battery.batteryLevel);

var _batteryState;
_battery.onBatteryStateChanged.listen((BatteryState state) {
  _batteryState = state;
  print(_batteryState);
});
```

Comment: I do not want to be notified when the state changes, just need to know if it is currently connected to power.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to just query the current state, like there is for the battery level

Comment: @JeffP You get a value when you first listen to the stream, and then every time the battery status changes. I edited the answer to give an example

Comment: I will try that.  There is no dispose method on Battery?

Comment: I am getting the following while running on the android simulator: E/flutter (28053): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UNAVAILABLE, Charging status unavailable, null)
E/flutter (28053): null